# How do I call my jQuery function so that it will run in my document.ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application I have a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pageLoad(sender, args){
    $('#nursing').click(function () {
        document.getElementById("ddlPositionType").selectedIndex = 1;
        $("#btnSearch").click();
        a.href = "#";
        return false;
    });
}
</script>
```

Then below it I am attempting to call it when the page is loaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#nursing').click();
});
</script>
```

This does not fire when the page load as it should and it causes no errors in my console. What is most confusing is that if I took from `document` to `return false` from the first code block and placed it where I am trying to call the `$('nursing').click();` the code will run like it is supposed to.

As reference `#nursing` is simply a link used on my slider to control content.

```
<a id="nursing" class="oslide">Nursing Positions</a>
```

Comment: And did you actually call `pageLoad` somewhere, or did you just expect the code inside it to be ran ?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your click event in a function when you have no need to and don't use the arguments you created in the function?

Comment: All of the code in pageLoad works. I will add a c# tag as it is on a web form

Comment: @j08691 The code is on a c# webform. I am using the code in the arguments. Actually the code will not work outside the pageLoad function. I also should mention that I am using an update panel which also works as it should. Basically I am using buttons on my slider to control and fire c# elements

Comment: Are you sure that your `document.ready` function isn't being called before pageLoad() and just isn't doing anything since the handler hasn't been added yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've written in pageLoad is an instruction to set up a click handler.  That setup will not be executed unless the pageLoad function is called prior to your call to click the button in document.ready.  The easy fix may be to simply modify your code so that it calls pageLoad, and then clicks the anchor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    pageLoad();
    $('#nursing').click();
});
</script>
```

But this seems a lot of overkill to call a function by performing a  click.  Why not just make a function out of the click handler and call that code in document.ready instead?  If you still need the click handler, call the function in the click handler.

```
function onNursingClick() {
    document.getElementById("ddlPositionType").selectedIndex = 1;
    //... and so on....
}

function pageLoad() {
    $("#nursing").click(onNursingClick);
}

$(function() {  //shorthand for $(document).ready(...);
   onNursingClick();
   pageLoad();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because in your document.ready script you're not calling the function pageLoad() that you created earlier. You are firing a click event. So try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){     //Jquery shorthand for document.ready
        pageLoad(sender, args); //pass in what you need
    });
</script>
```